# How to copy one row item to another row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following table:

```
Student_ID  Description 
1       0x
2       0x1G800....
3       0x1F800....
```

Student_ID 1 has empty value how can i copy student_ID 2's value in 1 using sql query.

Comment: Just once or for every empty row, use next to update?

Comment: What is considered empty?  The `0x` for student 1 doesn't look like an empty value

Comment: @bluefeet - It is binary data. so 0x is empty.

Comment: @NoviceMe -- is that all you're trying to do?  Feels like I'm missing something?

Comment: Simple Update statement should do it? Or where is the problem?

Comment: @Magnus - Just wanted to make sure that simple update will update binary data field otherwise no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this all you're looking for?

```
Update Student
SET Description = (SELECT Description FROM Student WHERE Student_ID = 2)
WHERE Student_ID = 1
```

Or using a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE S 
SET S.Description = S2.Description
FROM Student S JOIN
    Student S2 ON S2.Student_ID = 2
WHERE S.Student_Id = 1
```

Good luck.

Comment: sgeddes - Yes, thank you! Just wasnt sure if it will work for binary stream.